# Instance model in eager loading has been null laravel

Tags: laravel

I get menu and it childs by:

```
Menu::with('getChilds')->where(['group' => 1])->get();
```

In Menu model:

```
public function getChilds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent', 'id')->where(['group' => $this->group])->with('getChilds');
}
```

But why $this->group return null ?. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `group` in model query.

You need to customize your Eloquent query

```
Menu::with(['getChilds' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('group',1);
}])->get();
```

In Menu model.

```
public function getChilds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent', 'id');
}
```

Comment: As you can see in model i call back with('getChilds') to get submenu multi level, that's why I have to add the condition to get submenu with unlimited depth, your X gives you only 1 submenu level. Also my question is why $this->group return null, I can't use this in this case right ?.